# How make my GDB understand new instructions?

Tags: gdb, 64-bit

I implemented some additional x86 instructions on QEMU for research purpose.

To provide debugging facility for these newly added instructions,

I want GDB understand my new instructions when it debugs binary.

(Now it appears as bad instructions...)

Is there any method that i can do it without modifying GDB source code?

Such as inserting modules... or whatever. Thanks:)

Comment: If it needs source code modification, please let me know how can

Answer (score 1):

gdb relies on the `opcodes` library to know how to disassemble.  So, to see your new instructions, you simply have to modify this library.  `opcodes` lives in the gdb source tree.

Comment: I think it would be really good if gdb cab understand new instruction inserted as a module... :(